# Can we add some more trigger words to the one-flag-comment-delete mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags, comment-flags

We just had a [rather unsavoury answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075118/python-classes-comparison/62075203#62075203) on SO from someone distinctly unhappy with the service they received. To put it mildly.

In particular, there were these two comments under the post:

> [image]

I've flagged both, but neither one was auto-deleted after one flag. The second I can kind of understand; the first should definitely trigger an insta-delete. Can we review the list of triggers for the mechanism and add some new entries?

Comment: Yiiiikes... I'm really surprised that first one survived your flag.

Comment: I am wondering if it would make sense to have some sort of mechanism that allows moderators to inspect / update   the corresponding filter file "directly"?

Comment: Fwiw: the list (actually, expression) is a lot shorter than most folks would expect; there's a high possibility for false-positives in nearly anything, and avoiding those can also restrict the impact. Generally, I would respond to requests for additions by checking the past year of comments for occurrences, and adding only if there were enough to warrant it. Jason's machine learning system may offer some better options there, someday.

Comment: Scunthorpe.....

Comment: @Martin! The children!

Comment: @MartinJames Don't get me started :)

Comment: @Shog9 During your time here, was that list ever reviewed for additions that are no longer necessary? For example, I don't imagine that there are many remaining comments about the rate of acceptance from back when that feature existed, and comments made about it *today* are likely referring to it from a meta context, so it makes sense to not have it as an auto-delete keyword and instead have each such comment manually (as there aren't many past ones).

Comment: They were reviewed when they caused problems, @sonic. The accept expression was reviewed at least twice and made more specific / selective; others were dropped entirely when no recent examples of abuse could be found to match.